# flexible ordering of records in storage

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

We have many records in our storage stat should be kept ordered.
These records are managed via usual CRUD API: so user can add new records, change order of existing records, etc. The storage we use for records is not transactional (actually it is MongoDB). And we fire event for a record when it is updated, so that consumers can actually use the API to fetch updated version of record.

Let me stress this again: records should be kept ordered both when presenting them for modification in CRUD application and for consumers who are reading the state via events.

If we decide to use some integer field to keep track of records order, then we have to update many records when the order of some of them is changed. For example, we had

```
Fox order=1
Bear order=2
Cat order=3
```

Then we decide to add Wombat as second record - we have to update order of Bear and Cat:

```
Fox order=1
Wombat order=2
Bear order=3
Cat order=4
```

Imagine to have lots of records to be shifted that way - this can become serious problem, since we will fire change events for all of them and consumers will basically have to resync the entire storage.

If we go with linked list approach (each record keeps track of its neighbors) then reordering becomes easier, but consumers can find themselves in an inconsistent state. For example we had:

```
Fox next=Bear previous=none
Bear next=Cat previous=Fox
Cat next=none previous=Bear
```

Then we add Wombat as second record:

```
Fox next=Wombat previous=none
Wombat next=Bear previous=Fox
Bear next=Cat previous=Wombat
Cat next=none previous=Bear
```

The problem is that consumer can get first the event that Fox is changed with its next record being Wombat, before actually getting event about Wombat being created. If consumer performs some aggregating operation at this point - it will fail because its replica of records is inconsistent.

Is there any structure or approach that keeps records ordered, allows arbitrary inserting/reordering/deleting and yet avoids the need for transactions?

Comment: Perhaps a separate record that stores the order? This, too, will be inconsistent if, for example, you delete a record and somebody grabs the order record before you update it: the ordering record will show a non-existent record. Same thing can happen if you insert a record and the client gets the ordering before you update it: the client won't see the new record. But that's something you have to live with when you're working with a non-transactional data store. One way to get around the problem is have clients call an API for the data. That way, they never see the inconsistency.

Comment: Basically, non-transactional and perfect consistency are mutually exclusive requirements. If you want perfect consistency, then you have to go transactional. If you want non-transactional, then you have to accept the possibility of inconsistency.